# Detect when an image with no background shown on video

Tags: android, image, video, video-processing

I have a video taken using my app by the user.

How can I detect when an image with no background is shown on the video?

Comment: Not enough information to help you... **(1)** You have a video? can we see such an example? **(2)** Define what exactly "image with no background" means regarding video recording. Do you have an example (frame grab) of such a thing? **(3)** What are you really trying to achieve in the end? (there might be a better solution than trying detect non-background images in video frames)...

Comment: @VC.One Sorry for the long time to wait for an answer, I was on a vacation. **(1)** The video is being taken by the user within the app. **(2)** I meant that some sort of a shape, like a white triangle (so the image won't be a square image who contains a triangle, but an image which triangle shaped. **(3)** What I want to achieve, like I said in my question is to detect when this shape will be shown on the video.